# How to avoid submitting a form when creating a new content, depending on some criteria?

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

Let's suppose I have a content type **Person**, and I don't want the field **Name** to contain the text **AAA**.

What would be the best way of avoid submitting the form if that happens?

For example:
- Hiding the **Save** button
- Submitting it, but return to the same page with that field marked as *red*, or just show a message...

**This is just an example**. I'm asking it because sometimes I need to do a query to the database and see if some records exist, or something like that...

**Edit**:
I have edited the `template.php` file under the theme folder I'm using, and I have added the functions:

- `theme_theme()`
- `theme_formId($form)`

In the 2nd function, I've modified the form to see Drupal is calling this function, and yes, it works...

Then I did the following in the 2nd function:

`$form['#validate'] = array('my_validate_function');`

and under `my_validate_function($form, &$form_state)` I just wrote `form_set_error('', t('Testing...'));` and nothing seems to be happening: I can still create a new content without problems :(

**What am I missing here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add validation callbacks to any form in Drupal using the [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/group/form_api). Specifically, you can use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to add a validation callback to the [`$form['#validate']`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html#validate) element.

Comment: let me ask you something. Where should I declare that callback? in my template.php?

Comment: The best practice here would be to declare this code in a custom module. Putting this code in your theme won't work in Drupal 6 (and even in 7, custom validators should be placed in a custom module rather than in a theme).

Comment: I will read how to create custom modules, and I'll give it a try. Will let people now how it was...

Comment: It worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom validation handler, and define your criteria.

Comment: Could you be more specific about this? I'll edit my question to say what I've tried so far.